# Rails 4 - Associations - adding team mates to teams

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

I'm having trouble with my Rails 4 app.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails with some modifications.

The tutorial skips over a few steps that are considered by the writer to be too easy to bother with - I think that's where I'm getting stuck.

I have models for profile, project, team and user.

The associations are:

Profile.rb

```
has_many :teams, foreign_key: "team_mate_id"
  has_many :team_projects, through: :teams, source: :project
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
```

Project.rb

```
belongs_to :profile
    has_one :team
    has_many :team_mates, through: :team
    has_many :invites
```

Team.rb

```
belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :team_mate, class_name: "Profile"
```

Invite.rb

```
belongs_to :project
      belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'Profile'
      belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'Profile'
```

In my routes, I have:

```
resources :invites
resources :teams    
resources :profiles, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      resources :projects do
        member do 
          put "invite_team_mates" => "projects/invite_team_mates", as: :invitation
        end
```

In my projects views folder, I have a partial with the invite form:

```
<%= form_for @invite , :url => invites_path do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @invite.project_id %>
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
            <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
            <% end %>
```

I have also tried this as a general file called invite_team_mates.html.erb inside the project views folder and made a matching action for it in the projects controller, which has the action below: (with the route shown above for that specific action).

```
def invite_team_mate
    project = Project.find(params[:id])
    authorize @project
  end
```

I'm also not sure if I have to change the opening line of form_for @invite should be something to do with @project.invite. Im not sure.

I also have an invites controller with:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @invite = Invite.new
    end

    def create
      @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
      @invite.sender_id = current_user.profile.id
      if @invite.save

        #if the user already exists
        if @invite.recipient != nil 

           #send existing user email invitation to join project team
           InviteMailer.existing_user_invite(@invite).deliver 

           #Add the user to the user group - inivte rsvp pending
           @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)
        else
            #send new user email invitation to join as a general user as well as join this project team
           InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
        end
      else
         # oh no, creating an new invitation failed
      end
    end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invite
      @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invite_params
      params[:invite].permit(:email)
    end   
end
```

Im really stuck for how to hang all of this together.

My objective is to allow a user who creates a project to invite others to join the project team. I'm not getting far with this. When I try, to save all this and open the project, I get an error that says:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

The error highlights this line of the invites form partial:

```
<%= form_for @invite , :url => invites_path do |f| %>
```

When I try to change this line to use simple form syntax, as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@invite, :url => invites_path) do |f| %>
```

I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I think that might have something to do with the form being for @invite when it is saved in the projects views folder.

Can anyone see what's gone wrong?

**update - terminal lines**

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass:
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/model_naming.rb:9:in `model_name_from_record_or_class'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb:47:in `dom_class'
  simple_form (3.2.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:62:in `simple_form_css_class'
  simple_form (3.2.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:22:in `simple_form_for'
  app/views/projects/_invite_team_mate.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_projects__invite_team_mate_html_erb___1258064784578419157_70357207009700'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
  app/views/projects/show.html.erb:976:in `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb__3676206074319755518_70357179499400'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
```

These lines go on and on - im not sure if this is what you mean by 'backtrace'

Comment: This is quite a lot of detail for what is likely a small problem.  Let's instead work backwards from the error.  You are getting an `undefined method .. for nil:NilClass` error.  That's the most common error novice rubyists encounter.  It means you are trying to invoke a method on an object that is nil (aka NULL). We need to figure out which object is being set to nil and why. Could you please share the backtrace of the error so we can determine which particular line is causing the exception?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by 'backtrace'. I put byebug (and then debugger) into the form above the line that says  <%= simple_form_for(@invite, :url => invites_path) do |f| %>. I've shown the lines in the terminal above that come after trying it that way

Comment: Yeah those extra "terminal lines" are what I meant by backtrace.  I believe the key line from the output is `app/views/projects/show.html.erb:976`.  What do you have for line 976 of `app/views/projects/show.html.erb`?

Comment: It's this:                 <%= render :partial => 'projects/invite_team_mate'  %>

Comment: That's the partial that has the invite form in it

Comment: Ah, my bad, it looks like it is coming from line 6 of your `_invite_team_mate.html.erb`.  Are you sure `@invite` is not nil?  (perhaps do a `puts @invite` in your controller or use `bye_bug` to see the value of `@invite`?

Comment: If you render the `_invite_team_mate.html.erb` template from the `show.html.erb` view, then the problem is that the variable `@invite` is not being defined in the `show` action in the `ProjectsController`. Add `@invite = Invite.new` at the start of the method `ProjectsController#show`

Comment: Thank you both. That's really very much appreciated. I added invite.new to the projects controller and now I can use the form. Thanks a lot!