# Rails 4 - argument error - scoped invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, arguments

I'm trying to figure out how to follow along with the ideas in this tutorial:

https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails

I'm getting stuck on how to invite users. I have a form to invite a user that works on the show page. It works up to the point where I press send. Then I get an error which says:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

I don't know what an argument is. I'm not sure what the one thing is that is referred to as the given argument and I don't know what the system expects. I've been trying to figure out what an argument is and whether I need to try to figure out how to increase the expectation or reduce what ever it is that has been given that is being counted.

I found this article which tries to explain what an argument is: http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/ but of all the examples given, it doesn't show a method without an argument and it doesn't actually say what the argument is there to do. I'm still confused.

The references in the error message are to:

```
def existing_user_invite
    mail(
      :subject => "You've been invited to join a team",
      :to  => 'hello@you.com',
      :from => 'me@you.com',
      :html_body => ''
      # :track_opens => 'true'
      )
  end
```

It also refers to this line in my invites create action:

```
def create
      @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
      @invite.sender_id = current_user.profile.id
      if @invite.save
           InviteMailer.existing_user_invite(@invite).deliver 

           @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)
        else
            #send new user email invitation to join as a user and then as part of this team
           @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)

           # InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
        end

         # oh no, creating an new invitation failed

    end
```

The tutorial create method shows this:

```
def create
  @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
  @invite.sender_id = current_user.id
  if @invite.save

    #if the user already exists
    if @invite.recipient != nil 

       #send a notification email
       InviteMailer.existing_user_invite(@invite).deliver 

       #Add the user to the user group
       @invite.recipient.user_groups.push(@invite.user_group)
    else
       InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
    end
  else
     # oh no, creating an new invitation failed
  end
end
```

I'm finding it difficult generally to find rails or ruby resources that explain what components are. I'm pinning my previous questions, to offer more background about the problem I'm trying to solve:

[Rails 4 - Invite team mates to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626244/rails-4-invite-team-mates-to-project)

[Rails 4 - Associations - adding team mates to teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041877/rails-4-associations-adding-team-mates-to-teams)

Invite_mailer.rb

```
class InviteMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  # include Devise::Mailers::Helpers


  def existing_user_invite(invite)
    mail(
      :subject => "You've been invited to join a research project team",
      :to  => 'hello@you.com',
      :from => 'me@you.com',
      :html_body => ''
      # :track_opens => 'true'
      )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

You have `existing_user_invite` which *don't expect any arguments* to it, but you are passing one(*`existing_user_invite(@invite)`*). If you want to pass an argument to that method, then you should change it to allow an argument.

```
def existing_user_invite(invite)
  mail(
  :subject => "You've been invited to join a team", 
  :to  => 'hello@you.com', 
  :from => 'me@you.com', 
  :html_body => '' 
  # :track_opens => 'true'
  )
end
```

Comment: Hi Pavan, I tried this, but it leads to an error that says: "stack level too deep". From what I can decipher, that error happens because the code is stuck in a loop: either a method calling itself, or two methods calling each other repeatedly. I don't know what that means or how it could happen from adding an argument. I'll try to learn more about that next.

Comment: @Mel didn't expect that. Can you try changing the argument name to something else.. like `def existing_user_invite(invitation)`

Comment: but what does (invitation) mean? Is it just a random word that I'm supposed to insert?

Comment: I tried (invitation) - but it gives the same error. I'm even more confused at the suggestion though - if i can just put any word in as the argument - why does it complain if I have no word at all?

Comment: @mel if you declare a method, which should not receive any arguments, and call it by passing an argument - that is the error you are going to receive. Regarding the naming of the argument- it simply does not matter, because the argument will be a variable in the method's scope. Though it is better to name it differently if you have a method with the same name as your argument in the same class

Comment: @Kkulikovskis - when you say it doesn't matter, do you mean if i write (tomatoes) in the method and don't have that word anywhere else in my app, that its somehow valid? I don't know what you mean by saying "argument will be a variable in the method's scope" - I don't know where to start researching what that means. Thanks for the help, but I haven't understood what you mean

Comment: @mel exactly what you said. This very crucial and basic for making an App and should be understood BEFORE you even create a new Rails app: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to help. Having read that article, I still can't see how writing tomatoes in brackets as an argument to the method gives me something useful. I haven't figured out what a method's scope is for it to have a variable. I have been trying for years to grasp these crucial basic things -- but not seeing the connect between writing a random word in brackets after a method and the rest of the material about components of code. I'm afraid I'm more confused now than I was before I asked. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

@Pavan's answer explains why you are getting the first error

`wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

Then the second question is, why you are getting the `stack level too deep`

My guess is `existing_user_invite` method is in the wrong class. You may be having it in `Invite` model, but it should really go to `InviteMailer`

So try

```
#app/mailers/invite_mailer.rb
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

  # there may be other methods in this class too 

  def existing_user_invite(invite)
     mail(
       :subject => "You've been invited to join a team", 
       :to  => 'hello@you.com', 
       :from => 'me@you.com', 
       :html_body => '' 
       # :track_opens => 'true'
      )
  end
end
```

Please note that `existing_user_invite` method take 1 argument (invite), which u r passing from the controller. (as @Pavan mentioned)

However if you are still having issues, please post the error full track trace, so that makes easier to locate the issue. :)

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks so much for having a look. But the existing_user_invite(invite) is in the invite_mailer.rb file.